# Chest trauma during dips on horizontal bars during workout, pain in the upper part of anterior chest wall, hard to breath deeply

Tags: pain, chest, dips

Sorry if it's considered off-topic here, I hoped there will be plenty of people to share their experience, as I now know that's a very frequent trauma during this kind of exercise (should I knew it before..)

About 10 days ago I was doing dips on horizontal bars - when at some point I abruptly descended lower than usual, and something in my chest snapped (there was loud, distinctive crack sound). There was some sort of pain at first, not acute, more like dull and somewhat suffocating. But in a few minutes it got better and I more or less recovered. I was even able to finish my training (though I didn't stress out my chest any more that day).

I wasn't able to visit clinic back then, and it's hard for me to do so today as well (I'm not a permanent resident of the country where I currently live, it's hard and expensive to get medical help for me here).

Pain got back that very night, and it got worse the day after. Since then I've been taking over the counter painkillers to be able to sleep (somehow, at least). It doesn't fix the pain, but makes it less severe and bearable. I don't see any visual signs of severe trauma - no muscle rupture signs, or change in my chest's form, I can move my limbs freely (though sometimes it's painful). When palpating my chest plate, I can feel a little bump at its upper part, in an area where 2nd or 3rd pairs of ribs are attached - and it's very painful if I press it.

The pain also got better over these days (10 days so far), before I was afraid of a little cough as each such cough resulted in sever pain; I couldn't move my upper body freely without being afraid of severe pain in the chest. Now I can cough (lightly) without any pain, I can do my house chores almost without pain manifesting itself.

The most unsettling thing for me currently is breathing problem. I'm 100% sure it's not a heart or lung issue, as I would have noticed it long ago during my workouts, and it only appeared after the trauma. I'm not suffocating, but you probably know that feel when you want to take a deep, long breath sometimes? When that time comes for me and I try, it feels like my lungs can't open up fully; like something is blocking them. Sometimes it's just painful to breath so deeply, so I would think my body just prevents me from doing it, on a very low level - but it's still the same even under painkillers when I don't feel any pain. Then sometimes it just works, and I can inhale very deeply (especially often when lying on a couch).

Is it a normal progress of recovering from a trauma like this? How long does it usually take to recover from a trauma like this (I'm assuming some sprain or crack in a cartilage)? I also looked [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_syndrome) up, and symptoms match my case as well.

Comment: Medical diagnoses are off-topic here. You should consult a professional.

Comment: Go see a doc. You f'ed up unfortunately. How much do you bench?